# Type.GetMember get only members from enum and not from object

Tags: c#, types, enums, memberinfo

I am using `Type.GetMember` to get `enum` member. And when my enum value is `Equals`. It returns the `Equals` method which is inherited from object. So how could i retrieve only the enum member and not the members from object.

**Enum**

```
enum MyEnum{
 Equals,
 NotEquals
}

MemberInfo[] member = typeof(MyEnum).GetMember("Equals"); 
//Returns both Equals method from object and also the member from enum.
```

So how could i get the `Equals` from `enum` alone?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a binding flag:

```
MemberInfo[] member = typeof(MyEnum).GetMember("Equals", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Or just use `GetField`:

```
FieldInfo member = typeof(MyEnum).GetField(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: ``Type.GetMember(string, BindingFlags)`` returns a ``MemberInfo[]``

Answer (score 1):

You could use bindingflag `DeclaredOnly`.

```
MemberInfo[] member = typeof(MyEnum).GetMember("Equals", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

From msdn (DeclaredOnly):

> Specifies that only members declared at the level of the supplied type's hierarchy should be considered. Inherited members are not considered.

Comment: Provide a code sample as well to make it a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "Equals");
```

if I correctly understand your question.